# Nextflow is skipping one of the process and runs the next process

Tags: nextflow

I am running nextflow based gatk based pipeline. All the processes are working fine till panelnormalone process but skips the DBcreation process and starts running the next process (tumorsamplenamerun). I am sharing the part of my code where i am getting issue.

```
  process normalsamplenamerun {
  
  publishDir params.trim, mode : 'copy' 

  input:
  tuple val(pair_id), file(recal_readsbamfile)

  output:
  tuple val(pair_id),file(normal_samplefile), emit : SM_normalbam
  tuple val(pair_id),file(normal_samplefile_bai), emit : SM_normal_bai


  script:
  normal_samplefile = pair_id + '_recal_reads_SM.bam'
  normal_samplefile_bai = pair_id + '_recal_reads_SM.bai'

  """
    
  ./gatk./gatk --java-options "-Xmx24G" AddOrReplaceReadGroups --INPUT $recal_readsbamfile    --OUTPUT $normal_samplefile --RGLB lib1 --RGPL illumina --RGPU NONE --RGSM NORMAL_$pair_id
  ./gatk./gatk --java-options "-Xmx24G" BuildBamIndex --INPUT $normal_samplefile
  """

}

process panelnormalsone {

publishDir params.trim, mode : 'copy'

input:
tuple val(pair_id), file(normal_samplefile)
tuple val(pair_id), file(normal_samplefile_bai)

output:
tuple val(pair_id),file(panelvcfnormal_samplefile) emit : vcf_normal
tuple val(pair_id),file(panelvcfnormal_samplefile_stats) emit : vcf_stats
tuple val(pair_id),file(panelvcfnormal_samplefile_tbi)  emit : vcf_tbi


script:
panelvcfnormal_samplefile = pair_id + '_recal_somatic.vcf.gz'
panelvcfnormal_samplefile_stats = pair_id + '_recal_somatic.vcf.gz.stats'
panelvcfnormal_samplefile_tbi  =   pair_id + '_recal_somatic.vcf.gz.tbi'

"""

./gatk./gatk --java-options "-Xmx24G" Mutect2 -R ${params.reference} -I $normal_samplefile --max-mnp-distance 0 -O $panelvcfnormal_samplefile
"""

}

process DBcreation {

publishDir params.trim, mode : 'copy'

input:
file(panelvcfnormal_samplefile)
file(panelvcfnormal_samplefile_stats)
file(panelvcfnormal_samplefile_tbi)




output:
//path "${params.pondb}"
   
script:
sampleOpts = panelvcfnormal_samplefile.collect { p -> ("-V ${p.name}") } .join(' ')

""" 

./gatk./gatk --java-options "-Xmx24G" GenomicsDBImport -R ${params.reference} -L  ${params.intervalfile} --genomicsdb-workspace-path ${params.pondb} ${sampleOpts} --merge-input-intervals true --reader-threads 10 
./gatk./gatk CreateSomaticPanelOfNormals -R ${params.reference} --germline-resource ${params.germlineresource} -V gendb"://"${params.pondb} -O ${params.ponsfile}
```

"""

```
} 

process tumorsamplenamerun {
  
  publishDir params.trim, mode : 'copy' 

  input:
  tuple val(pair_id), file(recal_readsbamfile)

  output:
  tuple val(pair_id),file(tumor_samplefile), emit : SM_tumorbam
  tuple val(pair_id),file(tumor_samplefile_bai), emit : SM_tumorbam_bai


  script:
  tumor_samplefile = pair_id + '_recal_reads_SM.bam'
  tumor_samplefile_bai = pair_id + '_recal_reads_SM.bai'

  """
    
  ./gatk./gatk --java-options "-Xmx24G" AddOrReplaceReadGroups --INPUT $recal_readsbamfile --OUTPUT $tumor_samplefile --RGLB lib1 --RGPL illumina --RGPU NONE --RGSM TUMOR_$pair_id
  ./gatk./gatk --java-options "-Xmx24G" BuildBamIndex --INPUT $tumor_samplefile
  """
```

}

```
 workflow {

  panelnormalsone(normalsamplenamerun.out)
  samples = panelnormalsone.out.vcf_normal | map {  t -> t[1] }  
  stats = panelnormalsone.out.vcf_stats | map {  t -> t[1] } 
  tbi = panelnormalsone.out.vcf_tbi | map {  t -> t[1] } 
  DBcreation(samples.collect(),stats.collect(),tbi.collect()) 
  gatkrun.out.recal_readsbamfile
  | filter { pair_id, recal_readsbamfile -> !pair_id.contains("N") }
  | tumorsamplenamerun`


  97/f6890e] process > trimming (trim on {CaGB17_T}) [100%] 10 of 10 ✔
 [c7/6f21fd] process > BWAMEM (10)                   [100%] 10 of 10 ✔
 [ed/20534d] process > gatkrun (10)                  [100%] 6 of 6
 [77/5513b3] process > normalsamplenamerun (5)       [100%] 5 of 5
 [80/c3035e] process > panelnormalsone (5)           [100%] 5 of 5
 [-        ] process > DBcreation            -
 [6a/9657cf] process > tumorsamplenamerun (1)        [100%] 1 of 1
 [d3/5b9f35] process > MM (1)                        [100%] 1 of 1, failed: 1
```

As process MM run depends on DBcreation output but this process is not running which later on failed the MM process.However, if i execute the pipeline till DBcreation then its working fine and run this process too but running the whole pipeline (including processes after DBcreation process skips this process and moves to next process.

Please help me to resolve this error.

Comment: It's hard to say more definitely since you've only shared a few of the process scripts, so we can't see what is actually going on. But something that stands out is that in the `workflow` declaration, you have are calling a process called `GenomicsDBcreation`, but you've not included a process with that name. Instead, you have one called `DBcreation`, which seemingly isn't included in the workflow. 

Also, we can't see what process `MM` is and how it's input channels are created, so we can't comment on why it's failing as it shouldn't even get started if the workflow block is correct.

Comment: Sorry, i have rectified the name of the process its actually DBcreation only. The problem is with running of DBcreation process as MM is working fine if i got the result from DBcreation process. So, the problem is to run the DBcreation process

Comment: Ah, you're providing an absolute path to `MM` where you create the DB? I would suggest you still emit something like a variable from `DBcreation` that is used as input, even something as simple as `touch DB_READY`, as this will ensure MM will wait for `DBcreation` to finish. 

Can you explain what you are doing with `| map {  t -> t[1] }`?

Comment: Thanks for quick response.DBcreation is for the creation of panel of normals , for that i want to collect all of the output files produced by the panelnormalsone process and use as an input as a single run of the DBcreation process. Example is  DBcreation process run like -V file1 -V file2 -V file3 -V file4. Related to map operator, panelnormalsone.out.vcf_normal channel emits tuples with an id and a filenames and in order to select only the filenames i have used map operator

Comment: Hmm, unsure what is happening then, but you don't need to map the channel into a different structure. I'll put an answer since it's easier to format.

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing there is an error with how you are generating the channels for `DBcreation` and that's why it's not working. Here is how I would try to solve it.

```
process DBcreation {

publishDir params.trim, mode : 'copy'

input:
tuple val(sample_ID), path(samples)
tuple val(sample_ID), path(stats) // is this even needed here? 
tuple val(sample_ID), path(tbi) // is this even needed here? 

output:
path "DB_READY", emit: db_ready_state // This is just to ensure that the process finishes before 
   
script:
sampleOpts = samples.collect{ "-V ${it}") }.join(' ')

"""  
./gatk./gatk --java-options "-Xmx24G" GenomicsDBImport -R ${params.reference} \\
-L  ${params.intervalfile} \\
--genomicsdb-workspace-path ${params.pondb} ${sampleOpts} \\
--merge-input-intervals true \\
--reader-threads 10 

./gatk./gatk CreateSomaticPanelOfNormals -R ${params.reference} \\
--germline-resource ${params.germlineresource} \\
-V gendb"://"${params.pondb} \\
-O ${params.ponsfile} && touch DB_READY
"""
}
```

```
workflow {
  ...
  panelnormalsone(normalsamplenamerun.out)
  panelnormalsone
    .out
    .vcf_normal
    .collect()
    .set{ samples }

  panelnormalsone
    .out
    .vcf_stats 
    .collect()
    .set{ stats }

  panelnormalsone
    .out
    .vcf_tbi 
    .collect()
    .set{ tbi }

  DBcreation( samples, stats, tbi ) 
  ...
}
```

There are a few things that I noticed when copying your code:

1. `file` is deprecated, and the docs suggest you use `path` in its place.
2. Providing absolute paths for input files is not suggested, especially if you are using containers. So using `${params.reference}` can cause issues. Instead, create a value channel so the file will be correctly added the the process workDir.
3. I don't see where you are using the `panelnormalsone` stats or tbis in `DBcreation`. Do you need them?

Comment: Thanks again, i will go through it and update its implementation

Comment: i have implemented code according  to the changes suggested by you but again the same issue persists. With reference to the third point which you have mentioned, DBcreation process actually created a database and for that tbi and stats file serves as index files and are required.Thanks